Cortex-Xpanse By Palo Alto Networks Installation Steps
I was trying to install and run Cortex-Xpanse by Palo Alto Networks (An attack surface management tool) but didn't find any documentation or steps available on how it can be run.
I have found a website Cortex-Xpanse which contains a zip package to install Cortex-Xpanse with dependencies which consists of a set of Ansible-Playbooks but didn't really understand on how it can be run?
The following things I have tried so far:

I tried looking for any guidelines of this package on Github but didn't find any useful information

Even tried seeking help from Gen-AI tools but none of them provided an accurate answer on how it can be installed and run

Looked for guides/documentation online didn't find any useful resources


Any help in this matter is highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!!
